# Converting Detached object to persistent

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

As there are 3 states of objects in hibernate

1. Transient
2. persistent
3. detached

I know Transient state object can be converted to persistent once it it persisted by attaching it to a session
Can it be done with detached objects also? or detached object has no life in hibernate context as there is no record of it in the cache?

Comment: This pretty much answers your question - Modifying detached objects: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached

Comment: @DoeJohnson Thanks.

Comment: @DoeJohnson if I use update() in the second session and if the same is already loaded by the second session the would it throw any error?

Comment: Hmn, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "second session" or "error" in particular. Better post a new question.

Comment: second session : Here I mean, the object is loaded using the first session then the first session is closed which makes the object 'detached'. Now I open another session i.e. 'second session'. Using the second session I load the object again in some other reference. Now if I call update() for the older object using second session then will it throw any error? how would hibernet treat this senario